# How to pass data to asp.net page?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, xml, ajax

In my asp.net solution, I am using jquery to manipulate some html code. I then want to convert this into an xml code, and send it back to the same page via ajax. So that the c# code can read it and do server side things to it.

Whats the best way to do this? Currently, I am putting the xml code into a invisible text box, then make the asp.net ajax call, which then in c# I can read the text in the textbox.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be XML? I'd be tempted to use JSON instead, as it is considerably easier to work with on the client side.

Comment: you can use ajax to send the data to the backend, understand that the user can manipulate this data and you should be security conscious.

Comment: I agree with Charlie Kilian, use JSON instead of XML; if you use ASP.NET Page Methods then you can get JSON encoding for free from the server back to the client.

Comment: ok, how would I send a JSON request to the current .aspx page? And I believe its in jquery right (to send the JSON)? And how would I write the c# code to retrieve this value?

Comment: This post by Dave Ward shows exactly how to do the client and server pieces:  http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use json you can do:

In your aspx page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "webpage.aspx/doSomething", //doSomething is the method in the code-behind class
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{ data: 'data you want to pass to the C# method' }", // params to the doSomething method  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(msg) {
    // do something with the data the C# method returned
    },
   error: function(msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
   }
});
```

In your webpage.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
    private static <returnType> doSomething(string data){
    // manipulate the data var
   return <what you want>; 
   }
```